# How to add license key to Azure DevOps if trial expired

Tags: azure-devops

Was running trial of Azure DevOps Server and the trial expired. Have license key now and want to enter it, but there is no way to do so.  The online instructions reference fields/options that aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519477/finding-azure-devops-server-product-key).

Please follow [Upgrade Azure DevOps Server Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/express?view=azure-devops) to upgrade yours. You will need to upgrade your SQL Sever at the mean time.

For more information, please refer to [Buy access to Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub?view=azure-devops-2019) and [Pricing for Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/).